# How to implement properties in C++ concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

The C++ concepts are a relatively new idea in C++.
But we have few available explanation as to how it works.

```
struct contain {
public:
  using Tin = int;
  using Tout = int;
  Tout sqr(Tin x)
  {
    return x * x;
  }
  contain(int _x) : x(_x)
  {
  }
  int get_x() const
  {
    return x;
  }
private:
  int x;
};


int cube(contain u)
{
  int x = u.get_x();
  return x * x * x;
}
```

That is we want to have a concept that tests that contain contains **Tin**, **Tout** and a member function **Tout sqr(Tin)**. Would it also be possible to test if there is a non-member function **cube(contain)**?

Comment: Are you sure we're talking about the same thing? Concepts are meant to be used with template arguments, [like this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints). Are you asking for a concept that requires something with the same *interface* as your `contains`?

Comment: concepts arent that new idea. C++ has [named requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req) since long time, difference is that concepts are part of the language. Its not quite clear what you are asking. You have some template that wants to check if some `T` quacks like your `contains` quacks?

Comment: Yes.  Have you tried it?  Take the method syntax and change it in the obvioys way?

Comment: I can write a concept for the dependent type Tin, Tout. But I could do it for sqr and cube. In general, I found that there are too few examples of C++-concepts in the usual web site, most likely because they are new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That is we want to have a concept that tests that contain contains `Tin`, `Tout` and a member function `Tout sqr(Tin)`. Would it also be possible to test if there is a non-member function cube(contain)?

It kinda depends on what you mean by that. You can of course write a concept for something that behaves "enough like" `contain`:

```
#include <concepts>

template<class C>
concept ContainLike = requires(C c, typename C::Tin in) // typename only needed for Clang, until it implements P0634
{
    { c.sqr(in) } -> std::same_as<typename C::Tout>;
    cube(c);
};
```

[See it live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MlB8jCUmdPnYYfDJ)

The concept checks for a type `C`, that when given two hypothetical objects of type `C` and `C::Tin`, a list of explicit constraints holds:

1. `c.sqr(in)` is well-formed and returns `C::Tout`.
2. `cube(c)` is well-formed (can be found by ADL in our case). The type of the expression isn't constrained here.

Note that the test for `C::Tout` and `C::Tin` is implicit here. If `C` doesn't contain those types, it will be a substitution failure, which will make the concept not be satisfied (in a SFINAE friendly way).

Another thing worth mentioning is that this doesn't check `C` contains a `sqr` method whose parameter is a `Tin`. Rather it checks that a `Tin` may be passed as an argument (which may entail conversions to the actual parameter type). This is the more natural use of concepts: duck typing.